# Merge first columns with duplicated values and third column with different values

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following sheet in my Excel:

```
| Coordinator name | Coordinator Email | Employee Name |
|:-----------------|------------------:|:-------------:|
| XXXXXXXXXX       | XXXXXXX@XXX       |     YYYY     
| XXXXXXXXXX       | XXXXXXX@XXX       |     XPTO
```

So in this sheet I have a lot of same coordinator which have different employees names. What I want to do, is transform employees names column in values separated by comma for all equal coordinators values. Example:

```
| Coordinator name | Coordinator Email | Employee Name |
|:-----------------|------------------:|:-------------:|
| XXXXXXXXXX       | XXXXXXX@XXX       |     YYYY,XPTO     
| BBBBBBBBBB       | BBBBBBB@XXX       |     XYZ, ABC
```

I need this for sending a direct mail (mailing list) with Word, but I don't want to send for each coordinator more than one email with one employee in each one.

Comment: What have you tried? many similar questions exist on this site.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me site, nor is it a show me where to start site.

Comment: a pivot table would suffice?

Comment: Rather than change your source data I think it would be best to have your email code do the filtering. Post what you have already.

Comment: Hi @Nathan_Sav, tried that, but when trying to work with Word didn't work.

Comment: Hi @Absinthe, using Word I have tried the rules inside of it and another things. But the code above done the thing.

Comment: Sorry @ScottCraner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code,

```
Sub mergeDup()
Dim i As Long, str As String, j As Long
Columns("A:C").Sort key1:=Range("A2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
Sheets.Add.Name = "newSheet"
Rows(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("newSheet").Cells(1, 1)
j = Sheets("newSheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
str = Cells(2, 3)
For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i + 1, 1) Then
        str = str & "," & Cells(i + 1, 3)
    Else
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("newSheet").Cells(j + 1, 1)
        Sheets("newSheet").Cells(j + 1, 3) = str
        str = Cells(i + 1, 3)
        j = Sheets("newSheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

If your data range is in `columns A to C` as below,

[image]

the code creates a new sheet called `newSheet` and puts the values in it as below,

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Gowtham! Worked perfect!